# Content-length when redirecting in express

Tags: node.js, express

It seems that every time I try to redirect a user, express is wrongly adding a Content-Length to the header:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Output:

```
curl -I http://127.0.0.1:8080/action
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
X-Powered-By: Express
Location: /
Vary: Accept
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 35
Date: Thu, 24 Jul 2014 16:38:27 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Since the response doesn't have a body, I'm wondering why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in the spec that prevents responses with that status code from having a body. Most likely the content is some kind of human-readable message about the redirect.

So the `Content-Length` is the length of [the content you would ordinarily see](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/c6e620302097838e37663e3cb23168b29f641ad0/lib/response.js#L750-L763) if you were using a method other than HEAD.

Comment: But the body is empty!